# PGF: Change Label and Ticks distance without introducing whitespace

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a smaller plot that I want to embed into my text with `0.5\textwidth`. This throws of the balance between font size and information, so I changed the font-size to `\tiny`. But now my distances between ticks to axes and labels to ticks look to huge, so I moved both via `yticklabel style = {xshift=2pt}` and `ylabel shift = -4pt`. But this throws of the pgf-plot calculation since I get an increased whitespace around my figure.

Here's the code:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
\definecolor{chocolate19310053}{RGB}{193,100,53}
\definecolor{darkgray176}{RGB}{176,176,176}
\definecolor{darkslategray348596}{RGB}{34,85,96}

\begin{axis}[
height=0.62*0.5\figwidth,
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
width=0.5\figwidth,
x grid style={darkgray176},
xlabel={clean accuracy},
xmin=84.753, xmax=97.227,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={darkgray176},
ylabel={new test accuary},
ymin=57.6975704182106, ymax=98.515353789609,
ytick style={color=black},
font=\tiny,
ylabel shift = -4pt,
yticklabel style = {xshift=2pt},
xlabel shift = -4pt,
xticklabel style = {yshift=2pt},
mark size= 1.0pt,
]
\addplot [
  mark=*,
  only marks,
  scatter,
  scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
  \endscope
},
  scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
  \expanded{%
  \noexpand\definecolor{thispointdrawcolor}{RGB}{\drawcolor}%
  \noexpand\definecolor{thispointfillcolor}{RGB}{\fillcolor}%
  }%
  \scope[draw=thispointdrawcolor, fill=thispointfillcolor]%
},
  visualization depends on={value \thisrow{draw} \as \drawcolor},
  visualization depends on={value \thisrow{fill} \as \fillcolor}
]
table{%
x  y  draw  fill
85.32 59.8406374501992 145,71,46 145,71,46
94.87 74.4223107569721 145,71,46 145,71,46
96.66 77.9282868525897 145,71,46 145,71,46
95.83 77.2111553784861 145,71,46 145,71,46
95.08 77.3705179282869 145,71,46 145,71,46
94.97 77.7689243027888 145,71,46 145,71,46
93.24 72.8286852589641 145,71,46 145,71,46
93.1 71.9521912350598 145,71,46 145,71,46
94.75 73.5458167330677 145,71,46 145,71,46
94.77 75.2191235059761 145,71,46 145,71,46
92.23 78.5657370517928 145,71,46 145,71,46
92.23 72.7490039840637 145,71,46 145,71,46
};

\addplot [semithick, chocolate19310053]
table {%
85.3199996948242 61.5563278198242
96.6600036621094 78.7848129272461
};
\addplot [semithick, darkslategray348596]
table {%
85.3199996948242 85.3199996948242
96.6600036621094 96.6600036621094
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

this results in:

[image: the whitespace]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to alter the plot parameters the way you did to fit the graph into a `0.5\textwidth` width. `TikZ` and hence `pgfplots` has an option to scale the figure to a desired height/width ratio.

Without the preamble and other information I just inserted your code into a default document and commented out some lines causing errors in my compilation. Using `paracol` to define two columns of about `0.5\textwidth` and the `scale` option your plot fitted snugly inside the allocated column.

Thus this code should work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\columnratio{0.5,0.5}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\noindent   % to prevent indentation on first sentence
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed, scale=0.95]
    \definecolor{chocolate19310053}{RGB}{193,100,53}
    \definecolor{darkgray176}{RGB}{176,176,176}
    \definecolor{darkslategray348596}{RGB}{34,85,96}
    
    \begin{axis}[
        height=0.62*0.5\textwidth,  %<= \figwidth causes errors
        tick align=outside,
        tick pos=left,
        width=0.5\textwidth,            %<= \figwidth causes errors
        x grid style={darkgray176},
        xlabel={\large clean accuracy},
        xmin=84.753, xmax=97.227,
        xtick style={color=black},
        y grid style={darkgray176},
        ylabel={\large new test accuary},
        ymin=57.6975704182106, ymax=98.515353789609,
        ytick style={color=black},
        font=\small,
%       ylabel shift = -4pt,        %<= maybe for finetuning position
        yticklabel style = {xshift=2pt},
%       xlabel shift = -4pt,            %<= maybe for finetuning position
        xticklabel style = {yshift=2pt},
        mark size= 1.0pt,
        ]
        \addplot [
        mark=*,
        only marks,
        scatter,
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \expanded{%
                \noexpand\definecolor{thispointdrawcolor}{RGB}{\drawcolor}%
                \noexpand\definecolor{thispointfillcolor}{RGB}{\fillcolor}%
            }%
            \scope[draw=thispointdrawcolor, fill=thispointfillcolor]%
        },
        visualization depends on={value \thisrow{draw} \as \drawcolor},
        visualization depends on={value \thisrow{fill} \as \fillcolor}
        ]
        table{%
            x  y  draw  fill
            85.32 59.8406374501992 145,71,46 145,71,46
            94.87 74.4223107569721 145,71,46 145,71,46
            96.66 77.9282868525897 145,71,46 145,71,46
            95.83 77.2111553784861 145,71,46 145,71,46
            95.08 77.3705179282869 145,71,46 145,71,46
            94.97 77.7689243027888 145,71,46 145,71,46
            93.24 72.8286852589641 145,71,46 145,71,46
            93.1 71.9521912350598 145,71,46 145,71,46
            94.75 73.5458167330677 145,71,46 145,71,46
            94.77 75.2191235059761 145,71,46 145,71,46
            92.23 78.5657370517928 145,71,46 145,71,46
            92.23 72.7490039840637 145,71,46 145,71,46
        };
        
        \addplot [semithick, chocolate19310053]
        table {%
            85.3199996948242 61.5563278198242
            96.6600036621094 78.7848129272461
        };
        \addplot [semithick, darkslategray348596]
        table {%
            85.3199996948242 85.3199996948242
            96.6600036621094 96.6600036621094
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\switchcolumn
\lipsum[2]
\end{paracol}

\medskip
\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image: output pgfplots scaled]

Comment: this is not the solution I am interested in since it causes inconsistencies with font sizes. When I change to a smaller font I think the distances are not pleasant anymore hence my finetuning of the position. But now the whitespaces are off (as shown)

Comment: I updated my answer to make the graph more rectangluar. When I change the font size used in the article (here 11 pt) to 10pt or 12 pt, the plot changes accordingly and I see no alterations in the relative label positions. So you have be more specific about the font changes you want to make. Update your question with that and also include a full MWE with the preamble you are using to create this graph.